# Get an int from a written number

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, string-parsing, nsnumberformatter

I need to get an integer value from a written-out number, for example, get '3' in an `int` from the string `@"three"`. How could I do this?

Comment: (Google "parse english number" and you'll get a few ideas.)

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690974/convert-spelled-out-number-to-number

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
NSString * threeString = @"three";
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle;
formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSNumber * stringNumb = [formatter numberFromString:threeString];
int threeInt = [stringNumb intValue];
NSLog(@"ThreeInt: %i", threeInt);
```