# Spelled out number to NSNumber and overcoming NSNumberFormatter limitation

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter, openears

I'm using OpenEars to detect numbers spoken by the user and transcribed into text.
My goal is to transform the spelled out number into an NSNumber instance.

I have followed the advice of Rob in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690974/convert-spelled-out-number-to-number/) to do that. So i'm using NSNumberFormatter and setting the numberStyle to NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle before I call numberFromString.

Here's what my NSNumberFormatter initialization code looks like.

```
    _numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [_numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [_numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
    [_numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    [_numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
```

and then I'm NSLogging the result of numberFromString for a series of examples (just for testing)

First:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"eleven point three"]);
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"three point eleven"]);
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"three point one one"]);
```

and the results:

```
11.3
(null)
3.11
```

Second:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"thirty-four"]);
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"thirty four"]);
```

and the results:

```
34
3004
```

Third:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"three point one one"]);
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"one one point three"]);
```

and the results:

```
3.11
101.3
```

NSNumberFormatter seems to dislike anything other than single digits as decimals. It also seems to have a very strict set of rules when it comes to double digit numbers having to be separated by hyphens. And for the 3rd example it's just a mess...

Are these known limitations of NSNumberFormatter and would you have any suggestions as to overcoming this?

Are there any other limitations that I haven't encountered yet?

Many thanks for all input.

Comment: Do you see any difference if you set the local to `en_US_POSIX ` also I suggest you send a bug report to Apple.

Comment: @rckoenes I have indeed tried that too but no difference. Thanks for the bug report suggestion.